# Why I cannot use the operator [] on a pointer of std::array< int, 3 > to index value?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Code:

```
    void function(array<int,3> * ptr)
    {
        int temp = ptr[2]; // Error

        int temp = (*ptr)[2]; // Can work!
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        array<int,3> arr={1,2,3};
        function(&arr);
        return 0;
    }
```

I have no idea why the pointer cannot work like this：

```
    int *a = new int[3];
    a[2];
```

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Do you know what `array<int, 3> *` is?

Comment: I believe a better solution would be to use `void function(array<int,3> & ptr)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dealing with **pointer arithmetic**.

Inside of `function()`, you have a `std::array<int,3>*` pointer to an array of `std::array` objects (in your example, `&arr` can be treated as a pointer to an array of 1 `std::array` object).

Applying an index offset to a typed pointer will advance the pointer by a byte count equal to the index multiplied by the size of the *type* that is being pointed to.

So, given `ptr` is a `std::array<int,3>*` pointer, then `ptr[N]` (which is the same as `*(ptr + N)`) is the same as doing:

```cpp
*(
  reinterpret_cast< std::array<int,3>* >(
    reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(ptr)
    +
    (sizeof( std::array<int,3> ) * N)
  )
)
```

Or, more generally:

```cpp
*(
  reinterpret_cast< decltype(ptr) >(
    reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(ptr)
    +
    (sizeof( decltype(*ptr) ) * N)
  )
)
```

That is why `int temp = ptr[2];` does not work when `ptr` is a `std::array<int,3>*` pointer.  Dereferencing `ptr` will give you a `std::array<int,3>&` reference, not an `int` (note in your example that `ptr` is pointing at a single `std::array`, so `ptr[2]` is out-of-bounds, but `ptr[0]` and `*ptr` will work, since they are the same as `*(ptr+0)`).

And that is why `int temp = a[2];` does work when `a` is an `int*` pointer.  Dereferencing `a` will give you an `int&` reference.

To access a specific `int` element of a `std::array` object that is at a given index of an array pointed to by a `std::array*` pointer, you have to dereference the pointer first to access the `std::array`, and then you can invoke *its* `operator[]` separately, eg:

```cpp
std::array<int,3> arr = {1,2,3};
std::array<int,3> *ptr = &arr; // arr is equivalent to an array of 1 element

int temp = ptr[0][2]; // same as (*ptr).operator[](2)
```

Answer (score 1):

since `ptr` is a pointer to `std::array`, you should first get the `std::array`, and only then you can use the `operator[]`, otherwise you are using the `operator[]` on the pointer, which is not the same

Answer (score 1):

A pointer is just a number (memory address) refering to something else. It does not have a `[]` operator (even if the *pointed to thing* may have). You need to dereference the pointer to get at the thing it points to, then you can use `[]` if that thing supports it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int *a = new int[3];
    a[2];
```

Since `a` is an `int *`, `a[2]` is an `int`.

```
    void function(array<int,3> * ptr)
    {
        int temp = ptr[2]; // Error
```

Since `ptr` is an `array<int,3> *`, `ptr[2]` is an `array<int,3>`. So how could that assignment work?

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is an iterator for an array **of the pointed type**.

`int*` can be used as an iterator for an array of `int`. When you indirect through such pointer, you get an `int`.

`array<int,3> *` can be used as an iterator for an array of `array<int,3>`. When you indirect through such pointer, you **don't** get an `int`.

You haven't created an array of `array<int,3>`. You have created exactly one `array<int,3>`. There is no `array<int,3>` object at `ptr[2]` index.

Comment: A pointer to *any* variable can be treated as a pointer to an array of 1 element. So, given `array<int,3> arr={1,2,3}; function(&arr);` in the OP's original code, then `ptr[0]`  would be valid to access the `array` itself (not the `array`'s 1st element, that would be `ptr[0][0]` instead), but `ptr[2]` would not be valid.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Indeed, although I think mentioning that might confuse OP further.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution this problem would be using the `&` operator. It clears up a lot of uncertainty.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <array>

void function(std::array<int, 3>& arr1)
{
    int temp = arr1[2]; 

  
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 3> arr = {1,2,3};
    function(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While useful, this doesn't actually answer the OP's question.

Comment: @RemyLebeau okay, I'll delete it. This just seemed to be a better solution.

Comment: Sure, it is better, but it would help to explain WHY the original code does not work, and WHY this solution is better.